# Root Cause:Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I am Working with Java  Maven Project but I got some errors.please find I have given the project code below. I am Working in Eclipse Java EE IDE

This is My Project Code: [Link](https://www.blogger.com/blog/post/edit/7226897299712508249/6630596163099579963)

Tomcat Version v10.1

JDK 11

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error


Type Exception Report

Message Error instantiating servlet class [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet]

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception
jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet]
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:673)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:340)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)


Root Causejava.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1353)org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1165)java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1013)java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2352)org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:800)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Tomcat version 10 does not understand classes in the `javax.*` package. For this reason, many applications that have `javax` in their code, and those built for earlier versions of Java EE, which include servlets and JSP, as well as tag libraries such as JSTL, cannot run on the new version of Tomcat 10. Therefore, it is required rewrite the code and replace all references `javax` to `jakarta`, old libraries, and also update the application version in the descriptor, if available.

In all dependencies, you also need to remove all references to `javax.*`.

It you don't want to update a  java-ee version to JakartaEE then you should use Tomcat 9.